# cannot resolve symbol hashmap

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashmap

Here is my code in IntelliJ:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        Map<Integer, Integer> index = new Hashmap<>();
        
    }
```

The error is : cannot resolve symbol Hashmap. How can I solve this error?

}

Comment: Hashmap and HashMap are not the same, Java is case sensitive

Comment: Its called `HashMap`, not `Hashmap`, _PascalCase_. Voting to close, as caused by simple typo.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you import `java.util.*` there's no need to then import `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.Map` separately.

Answer (score 3):

Use the name as imported. Java is case-sensitive, there is no class named `Hashmap` with lowercase `m` in `java.util` package.

Use `HashMap` with an uppercase `M`.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> index = new HashMap<>();
```